# flush commands xemacs/elisp necessary?

Tags: elisp, xemacs

Im new to xemacs and linux in general, so consider me a newbie.
And i was wondering if there is a reason why elisp wouldn't execute a command or commands instantly.

I've the following code in my init.el:

```
(defun myClear ()
  "Clears console output buffer (F5)"
  (erase-buffer "*Shell Command Output*"))

(defun myMake ()
  "Executes make (F6)"
  (shell-command "make"))

(defun myClearMake ()
  "Clears console output buffer before executing make (F7)"
  (erase-buffer "*Shell Command Output*")
  (shell-command "make"))
```

they are bound to the keys F5-F7.
Hitting F7 does not produce the same result as hitting F5 first, then F6, which work as expected.

What happens instead is that the (erase-buffer ...) statement seems to be skipped, or maybe executed right before (shell-command ...). Since shell-command erases the buffer before dumping shell output anyway, its hard to tell.

What i expected: The console output gets cleared. This should be visible while make is still running and has not produced any output yet (which, in my case, is several seconds).

I have no idea how to further test this, and even though it seems like a common task, i couldn't find anything appropriate, or similar. Also consider that i'm not only interested in getting the mentioned behaviour, but also understanding what i did wrong.

Any links/pointer on elisp mechanics that explain this behaviour are appreciated.
Thanks,
    Tasche

Comment: I suggest that you use `M-x compile RET` instead of `shell-command`. This will create a compilation buffer where you can click on errors/warnings to be taken directly to the corresponding point in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm not much used to XEmacs, but rather to Emacs... There might be differences. But I can reproduce your problem with Emacs, so I hope the Emacs solution will also work for XEmacs.

Emacs doesn't redisplay the UI during command execution, which means hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> runs command `myClear`, then redraws the display while waiting for another input, then `myMake` is executed when you hit <kbd>F6</kbd>.
On the other hand, when you hit <kbd>F7</kbd>, the entire cycle `myClear`-`myMake` is executed, without any redisplay, making `erase-buffer` effects invisible. You eed to force a `redisplay` after `erase-buffer` to see its effects.

Below is a working example based on the code which you provided.

```
(defun myClear ()
  "Clears console output buffer (F5)"
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer "*Shell Command Output*"
    (erase-buffer)))

(defun myMake ()
  "Executes make (F6)"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "sleep 2; echo Hello World"))

(defun myClearMake ()
  "Clears console output buffer before executing make (F7)"
  (interactive)
  (myClear)
  (redisplay)
  (myMake))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'myClear)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'myMake)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'myClearMake)
```

Note that I had to do minor adjustments (maybe due to Emacs/XEmacs differences?)

Also note that a better way to do things like running make consists in using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile`<kbd>RET</kbd>. In particular, this will take care of erasing the buffer for you, run processes in the background (without hanging Emacs like your example does), and process the output to detect error/warning messages.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, this solved the nuisance, in both helping me understand whats wrong, and in improving on the method itself (by using compile).