# Run commands in Emacs asynchronously, but display output incrementally

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a utility function:

```
(defun execute-in-buffer (command-with-args buffer)
  "Execute a string COMMAND-WITH-ARGS representing a shell command with arguments,
inserting the results in BUFFER."
  (switch-to-buffer buffer)
  (insert (format ">>> %s\n" command-with-args))
  (let* ((command-args-list (s-split " " command-with-args))
         (command (car command-args-list))
         (args (cdr command-args-list)))
    (apply 'call-process command nil buffer t args)))
```

This allows me to do things like `(execute-in-buffer "ls /" (get-buffer-create "*my-output*")`. However, it's not well suited for slow commands. If I call a series of slow commands, I don't get any output until the very end:

```
(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*my-output")))
  (execute-in-buffer "sleep 10" buf)
  (execute-in-buffer "ls /" buf))
```

I want to be able to call synchronously, so the next command only runs after the previous one finishes. However, I want to see the output from my commands as they run. How would I do this?

(Example code is just for show, I'm happy to drop it in favour of something else.)

Comment: shouldn't you be using `with-current-buffer` or `set-buffer` instead of `switch-to-buffer`?

Comment: This is by design -- I want my output buffer to be visible. In other circumstances, I'd definitely use `with-current-buffer` or `set-buffer`.

Comment: in that case you need to use `set-buffer` and then `display-buffer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using synchronous processes**

If you want to stick with synchronous processes (e.g. using `call-process`), you need to call `(redisplay)` after each call to `execute-in-buffer` for the display to be updated and the output to be visible (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16734843/1225607) for more details). However, the output of each command will not be visible until the process terminates, and emacs will hang while the external processes are running.

**Using asynchronous processes**

Using asynchronous processes is a bit more complicated, but avoids hanging Emacs while the commands are running, which also solves the redisplay issue. The tricky part here is to sequentially chain all commands. Here is a bit of elisp which should do the trick:

```
(defun execute-commands (buffer &rest commands)
  "Execute a list of shell commands sequentially"
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (set (make-local-variable 'commands-list) commands)
    (start-next-command)))

(defun start-next-command ()
  "Run the first command in the list"
  (if (null commands-list)
      (insert "\nDone.")
    (let ((command  (car commands-list)))
      (setq commands-list (cdr commands-list))
      (insert (format ">>> %s\n" command))
      (let ((process (start-process-shell-command command (current-buffer) command)))
        (set-process-sentinel process 'sentinel)))))

(defun sentinel (p e)
  "After a process exited, call `start-next-command' again"
  (let ((buffer (process-buffer p)))
    (when (not (null buffer))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        ;(insert (format "Command `%s' %s" p e) )
        (start-next-command)))))

;; Example use
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*output*") (erase-buffer))
(execute-commands "*output*"
                  "echo 1"
                  "sleep 1"
                  "echo 2; sleep 1; echo 3"
                  "ls /")
```

Comment: Thanks, that improves matters considerably. However, ideally I'd like to see the output of a command live, rather than waiting for the command to terminate.

Comment: I added a solution based on asynchronous processes, which should solve this issue. Please see my edited answer

Comment: And thank you too: I think I'm going to use this technique in [a project of mine](http://github.com/ffevotte/slurm.el)

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
(async-shell-command "echo 1; sleep 10; echo 2; sleep 10; ls /" "*abcd*")
```

This can be adapted to do what you need?

Comment: Ooh, this is very close. In my original `execute-in-buffer`, I also display the commands I'm running before I run them. I can't see any neat way of doing this short of `(async-shell-command "echo \"echo 1\"; echo 1;")` etc.

Comment: If this is for personal use -- as against a productized functionality -- `(async-shell-command "set -xv; echo 1; sleep 10; echo 2; sleep 10; ls /" "*abcd*")` might work for you