# Emacs: if latexmk finishes okay, then show pdf, else display errors

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could anyone please give me hand with the step between the *first* `start-process` and the *second* `start-process`.  The *second* `start-process` that displays the pdf-file should run `only if` the *first* `start-process` finishes *without errors*.  There is probably some type of successful exit code that can be spotted, but I would need some help please in that regard.

I'm open to suggestions regarding how best to determine whether the *first* `start-process` finished without errors.  One method would be to look at the `output` buffer to determine whether the last line is equal to "Process `process` finished".  Making the *.pdf file can take a few *seconds* even if it is without errors, and the *second* `start-process` fails if it begins too early.  Sit-for is not the best option, since the *second* `start-process` should be aborted if the *first* `start-process` did not complete correctly.  Generating the `output` buffer also takes a couple of seconds, so checking the last line in the buffer would also need to wait until the *first* `start-process` finishes.  However, spotting a successful exit code (if such a thing exists) would be better than searching an output buffer for a string equals . . . .

FYI:  The .latexmkrc `$pdflatex` line of code puts a copy of the *.pdf back into the working directory, and the .latexmkrc `$out_dir` line of code puts all of the auxiliary files into the `/tmp` folder.  This is needed because Tex-Live for OSX does not support `$aux_dir`.  The result is a clean working directory containing just *.tex and *.pdf files.

```lisp
(defun latexmk ()
  ".latexmkrc should contain the following entries -- without the backslashes:
  $pdflatex .= ' && (cp \"%D\" \"%R.pdf\")';
  $force_mode = 1;
  $pdf_mode = 1;
  $out_dir = '/tmp';"
(interactive)
  (let* (
    (process (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
    (output (concat "*" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "*") )
    (latexmk "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl")
    (arg-1 "-interaction=nonstopmode")
    (arg-2 "-file-line-error")
    (arg-3 "-synctex=1")
    (arg-4 "-r")
    (arg-5 "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.latexmkrc")
    (pdf-file (concat "/tmp/" (car (split-string
      (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "\\.")) ".pdf"))
    (line (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))
    (skim "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline") )
  (if (buffer-modified-p)
    (save-buffer))
  (start-process process output latexmk arg-1 arg-2 arg-3 arg-4 arg-5 buffer-file-name)
  ;;  (if (last line of output buffer is "Process 'process' finished")
      (start-process "displayline" nil skim "-b" line pdf-file buffer-file-name)
    (switch-to-buffer output)
  ;;  )
    ))
```

---

**EDIT**:  A working solution based upon the concept outlined by Francesco in the answer below is available in a related thread:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816575/1225607) provides a way to chain asynchronous commands, using [sentinels](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#Sentinels) to wait for each command to terminate before running the following.

You need to adapt the sentinel in order to check the process exit status using [`process-exit-status`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html#Process-Information). A minimal working example for you should be along the lines of:

```lisp
(defun run-latexmk ()
  "Asynchronously run `latexmk' and attach a sentinel to it"
  (let ((process (start-process "latexmk" "*output*"
                                "/bin/sh" "-c" "echo KO; false")))
    (set-process-sentinel process 'latexmk-sentinel)))

(defun latexmk-sentinel (p e)
  "Display the pdf if `latexmk' was successful"
  (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
    (start-process "displaypdf" "*output*"
                   "/bin/echo" "DISPLAY PDF")))

;; Example use
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*output*") (erase-buffer))
(run-latexmk)
```