# Is it possible to remove a remote repository on Github through the command line?

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm currently running a bash script to automatically create a remote repository on Github using curl. I was wondering if there was any way of also deleting remote Github repositories on the command line as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [GitHub API "Delete repository"](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository) for that.
But you will need to use a [oauth token with the appropriate scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327004/6309))
You can see an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23039562/6309):

```
curl -X DELETE -H 'Authorization: token xxx' https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO-NAME
```

Comment: @FrankenstineJoe I believe you can import your curl command into Postman: https://www.daniellittle.xyz/curl-to-postman/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068925/6309

Comment: @VonC That really helped ,Thanks so much