# Simulate a specific CURL in PostMan

Tags: curl, httprequest, postman

I am using Postman to test some Curl requests to an API server. The API developers gave us the curl command, but I can't send it from the Postman. How to make such a request from the Postman?

```
curl -X POST "https://api-server.com/API/index.php/member/signin" -d "{"description":"","phone":"","lastname":"","app_version":"2.6.2","firstname":"","password":"my_pass","city":"","apikey":"213","lang":"fr","platform":"1","email":"email@example.com","pseudo":"example"}"

--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="profil.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01010048 ... a00fffd9>

—0xKhTmLbOuNdArY—
```

Comment: Related header replacement info: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/781#issuecomment-1225278296

Answer (score 971, accepted):

A simpler approach would be:

1. Open POSTMAN
2. Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
3. Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
4. Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder!
5. Click Send to post the command

Comment: I tried it and it worked partially. This is my curl request:
`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '
  {"customer_id":"812122",
   "event":"add_to_cart",
   "email": "abc@def.com",
  }' -u 9f4d7f5445e7: https://api.myapp.com/api/event`

After importing the body got imported correctly, the headers and the Url also got imported. Only the api key 9f4d7f5445e7 which is `-u 9f4d7f5445e7: https://api.myapp.com/api/v1/event` in the curl request did not import or may be Postman skipped it. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: I figure it out to import curl cmd by myselft. But took me sometime to find out where is the page with my imported curl, it looks like nothing happen when import a file/cmd. You then need click on the "code" button on the top right side (under save button). Then you will see whether your curl is loaded or not.

Comment: This approach didn't utilise the credentials I coded into it, so had to add those manually using Auth > Basic Auth ,inside the actual request using mouse & dropdowns. Worth mentioning I think, since the software's behaviour is such that it appears to have accepted & utilised the creds:all you get is a "please supply valid credentials" rather than "please supply some credentials".

Comment: @Onkaar can't we import other than cURL?

Comment: @Rito in my case, I have to specify key and value in 'params' tab

Comment: If this doesn't work for you then review your command for any non-functional paramters and remove them.  In my case a `curl ... -vv` wouldn't work, until the `-vv` was removed.

Comment: [About a failure case][ "curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/workflows/v1" -H  "accept: application/json" -F "workflowSource=@simple-hello.wdl" ]   if there is a file info in the curl command, it will fail when importing it into the postman. You need to fix the 'workflowSource' field by choosing the target file.

Comment: I was looking for this functionality for some time! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for web sockets, unfortunately.

Answer (score 23):

```
In addition to the answer
1. Open POSTMAN
2. Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
3. Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
4. Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder!
5. If -u admin:admin are not imported, just go to the Authorization 
   tab, select Basic Auth -> enter the user name eg admin and password eg admin.
This will automatically generate Authorization header based on Base64 encoder
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is a visual answer

For a quick 1 minute tutorial check this video [Run curl in Postman](https://youtu.be/CvutW041-2k) 
=======================================================================

1. Find the **Import** button on the top right corner
   [image]
2. Select **Raw** and paste your curl commands click **Continue -> Import**
   [image]
3. You can confirm request URL, params, and headers are imported properly.
   [image]

Answer (score 10):

I tried the approach mentioned by Onkaar Singh,

1. Open POSTMAN
2. Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
3. Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
4. Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder!

But the problem is it didn't work for the Apis which requires authorisation.

This was my curl request:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:
application/json" -X POST -d ' 
{"customer_id":"812122", "event":"add_to_cart", "email": "abc@def.com", }' 
-u 9f4d7f5445e7: https://api.myapp.com/api/event
```

After importing the body got imported correctly, the headers and the Url also got imported. Only the api key 9f4d7f5445e7 which is

```
-u 9f4d7f5445e7: https://api.myapp.com/api/v1/event
```

in the curl request did not import.

The way I solved it is, -u is basically used for Authorization. So while using it in Postman, you have to take the API key (which is `9f4d7f5445e7` in this case) and do Base64 Encode. Once encoded it will return the value `OWY0ZDdmNTQ0NWU3`. Then add a new header, the key name would be `Authorization` and key value would be `Basic OWY0ZDdmNTQ0NWU3`. After making that changes, the request worked for me.

There are online Base64 Encoders available, the one I used is http://www.url-encode-decode.com/base64-encode-decode/

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: on the authorization tab of postman just select Basic Auth and it will generate the Base64 header

Answer (score 10):

When you use Chrome `copy as cURL (bash)` and import in Postman, you need to do the following things:

1. Remove `--compressed` option
2. Replace `--data-raw` with `-d`

Otherwise you will get `invalid format for cURL` error.

Comment: This is no longer the case in new version (2022) of Postman. This is already handled by postman.

Answer (score 9):

1) Put `https://api-server.com/API/index.php/member/signin` in the url input box and choose `POST` from the dropdown

2) In Headers tab, enter:

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

3) In Body tab, select the `raw` radio button and write:

`{"description":"","phone":"","lastname":"","app_version":"2.6.2","firstname":"","password":"my_pass","city":"","apikey":"213","lang":"fr","platform":"1","email":"email@example.com","pseudo":"example"}`

select `form-data` radio button and write:

key = name Value = userfile   Select `Text`
key = filename   Select `File` and upload your profil.jpg

Answer (score 4):

sometimes whenever you copy cURL, it contains --compressed.
Remove it while import->Paste Raw Text-->click on import.
It will also solve the problem if you are getting the syntax error in postman while importing any cURL.

Generally, when people copy cURL from any proxy tools like Charles, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in multiple answers above you can import the cURL in POSTMAN directly. But if URL is authorized (or is not working for some reason)
ill suggest you can manually add all the data points as JSON in your postman body. take the API URL from the cURL.

for the Authorization part- just add an Authorization key and base 64 encoded string as value.

example:

`curl -u rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b:69b2e24411e384f91213f22a \    https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders    -X POST \    --data "amount=50000" \    --data "currency=INR" \    --data "receipt=Receipt #20" \    --data "payment_capture=1"    https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders`

`{
    "amount": "5000",
    "currency": "INR",
    "receipt": "Receipt #20",
    "payment_capture": "1"
}`

Headers:
`Authorization:Basic cnpwX3Rlc3RfWEk5QW5TU0N3RlhjZ0Y6dURjVThLZ3JiQVVnZ3JNS***U056V25J`
where "cnpwX3Rlc3RfWEk5QW5TU0N3RlhjZ0Y6dURjVThLZ3JiQVVnZ3JNS***U056V25J" is the encoded form of "rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b:69b2e24411e384f91213f22a"`

small tip: for encoding, you can easily go to your chrome console (right-click => inspect) and type :
`btoa("string you want to encode")` ( or use postman basic authorization)

Answer (score 1):

1. import from upper left
2. go to raw text and paste your code
3. import it
4. You can confirm request URL, params, and headers are imported properly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above answers, it works well.

If we paste curl requests with Authorization data in import, Postman will set all headers automatically. We only just pass row JSON data in the request body if needed or Upload images through form-data in the body.

This is just an example. Your API should be a different one (if your API allows)

```
curl -X POST 'https://verifyUser.abc.com/api/v1/verification' \
    -H 'secret: secret' \
    -H 'email: user@gmail.com' \
    -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
    -H 'authorizationtoken: bearer' \
    -F 'referenceFilePath= Add file path' \
    --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving to the [insomnia app](https://insomnia.rest/) completely.

Open the insomnia app, and paste the CURL request in the URL section of the request page.
This accepts CURL with small discrepancies and CURL copied from chrome Copy as CRUL command also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on import button from upper left
2. Prompt ask you to enter cURL, raw text and URL and then paste your code
3. Automatically You can confirm request URL, params, and headers are imported properly.
4. Click on send button from upper right corner, you can see the response of that cURL

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the others, I can give you a script in C# that converts curl(cmd) from Chrome dev tools into regular curl, which allows you to import it into postman.

```cs
string CmdCUrlToPostman(string input)
{
    var lines = 
        input
        .Split("\r\n")
        .ToList();

    for (int l = 0; l < lines.Count; l++)
    {
        var line = lines[l];

        if (line.EndsWith(" ^"))
            lines[l] = line = line.Substring(0, lines[l].Length - 2);

        if (line.StartsWith("  --data-raw"))
            lines[l] = line.Replace("  --data-raw", "  -d");
        else if (line.StartsWith("  --compressed"))
        {
            lines.RemoveAt(l);
            l--;
        }
        else if (line.StartsWith("  -H"))
            lines[l] = 
                line
                .Replace("^\\", "\\")
                .Replace("^\"", "\"");
    }

    return string.Join('\n', lines);
}
```