# How to convert cURL to postman?

Tags: curl, postman

Postman has built-in function to convert postman to cURL code, but if I want to convert cURL code to postman, How can I do this efficiently?
For example, cURL code as following;

```
curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=your_locale&device.os=your_device_os&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=your_instance_id&requestid=your_request_id" -H 'Authorization: Bearer your_access_token' -H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=16000' --data-binary @your_wave_file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate a specific CURL in PostMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman)

Answer (score 107):

By using the 'Import' functionality followed by 'Paste Raw Text'.

Explained in the official docs [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/importing_curl).

For the `body` it selects `raw` and expects the user to paste the content of the file into Postman. Alternatively you can toggle it to `binary` and upload the file manually while doing the actual request.

Comment: If your curl includes -u you'll need to manually paste the username:password into the Authorization tab with type Basic Auth

Comment: -u can also be passed as https://username:password@mydomain.com if you like to keep all things in the URL and not use the header.

Comment: The problem here is postman only accepts very specific formated cURL request that is generated by the postman. Any cURL we cannot give to postman to consume.