# Request work in curl -k but not in Postman disable SSL

Tags: ssl, curl, postman

I am working with Interactive Brokers Rest API: https://www1.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=45185

I can use my browser to ping their APIs without problem. Only I will get SSL cert warning.

I also tried to use `curl -k url`. It also works.

Then I tried to turn off the SSL certificate verfication in Postman and ping the api. It keeps loading (sending requests).

This is my setting:
[image]
[image]

Not sure whether "Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://localhost:5000/favicon.ico (“default-src”)." will affect. I try to use the network tab to look at this request but I got this message.

It also works using Swagger UI: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got it to work in curl, try importing the curl command into postman.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072437/13003509

You can also export the postman request as a curl, and compare two.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433083/13003509

Comment: The exported curl command from postman is "curl -X GET \
  https://localhost:5000/v1/portal/ibcust/entity/info" It does not work in command line.

And I have also import the curl comand to postman. It does not work too.

I guess it is SSL problem again. Curl -K works.