# Very simple POST in POSTMAN

Tags: http, curl, post, postman

I am doing a programming course right now and the person who runs the course wanted to check if his app is working by writing in console.

```
curl http://localhost:5000/users -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"email": "user10@email.com, "password": "secret", "username": "user10"}
```

He said that he is using Linux and so he can use cURL and recommended Postman for Windows. I downloaded Postman, but I have no idea how to achieve the same result in Postman. Could you help me and lead me by the hand because I tried to do it by myself but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate a specific CURL in PostMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman)

Comment: You can look at the official tutorial. I suggest you to learn by yourself this is better for you. https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests

Answer (score 0):

The official docs will give everything you need:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests

[image: Postman Request Builder]