# Convert cURL to Postman REST Call

Tags: rest, curl, postman

How can I convert the following cURL command to a Postman rest call?

```
curl -X POST abc.com/input.import 
        -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        --data-urlencode "apiKey=123-456"
        --data-urlencode "secret=12/her"
        --data-urlencode "userKey=ApUR"
        --data-urlencode "email=fakeImportedAccount@example.com"
        --data-urlencode "profile={'firstName':'John','lastName':'Kira'}"
```

I tried the following:

URL: (POST) abc.com/input.import

Header: Content-Type:application/json

Body:

```
{
    "apiKey":"123-456",
    "userKey":"ApUR",
    "secret":"12/her",
    "email":"fakeImportedAccount@example.com",
    "profile": {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Kira"
    }
}
```

EDIT: Raw-body format in Postman is required. Import creates the request in `"x-www-form-urlencoded"` form

Comment: it solved here :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman

Comment: Don't set the content-type to applicaiton/json. In the body part, select application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and it will automatically set the header for you. Then just set the different key, value pairs.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: In each example you're using a different content-type

Comment: @Evert are they not convertible?

Comment: If you want to do the same request in curl and postman, this needs to match.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yes, please see my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found: I have to url-encode every key value and send it with Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Header:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:

```
{
  "apiKey":"123-456",
  "userKey":"ApUR",
  "secret":"12%2Fher",
  "email":"fakeImportedAccount%40example.com",
  "profile":{
     "firstName":"John",
     "lastName":"Kira"
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem correct for the body. That actually works for you?

Answer (score 32):

The content-type is not `application/json`, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What you need to do is in the body tab, select `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The content-type header will automatically be set for you. The just start adding the key/value pairs (the --data-urlencoded arguments)

[image]

#### UPDATE

Unrelated, but for those looking for a way to post JSON (which is very common), you would use the "raw" radio button and then you would manually type in the JSON to the window they provide. Also you would set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.