# How to POST json parameters from Postman to Jenkins?

Tags: api, jenkins, postman

I need to call a Jenkins job using its API through Postman. This job requires parameters (HOST, VERBOSITY and PMSP).

Auth works using Jenkins token and header Content-type:application/json is used.

- I tried to call the endpoint https://jenkins_server/job/job_name/build/api/json adding the following body to the request but the result is **Nothing is submitted**, and **the job doesn't run**.
- I tried to call the endpoint https://jenkins_server/job/job_name/buildWithParameters/api/json adding the same body. I get **201 Created** (job is running) but **no parameters are given to the job**.

```
{
        "parameter": [
            {
                "name": "HOSTS",
                "value": "[linux]\n1.2.3.4"
            },
            {
                "name": "VERBOSITY",
                "value": "vv"
            },
            {
                "name": "SANS_PMSP",
                "value": true
            }
        ]
}
```

Is my JSON well constructed ? Which endpoint do I need to call ?

Comment: are you looking for this --> https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API  ??

ex -
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build 
  --user USER:TOKEN 
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'

Comment: I tried the solution with Curl and it works like a charm. But i'd like to **focus on Postman** !

Comment: This is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman

Comment: I have tested with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman and it is working.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect ! Good to know this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's `Postman` that you would like to focus on, you can import the curl command straight into the application.

[image: Postman curl]

This creates a new request for you to use and it populates this request, based on the details in the command.

[image: Postman]

From here, you should be able to add your own URL and point this at the location you need.