# error while importing curl request in Postman

Tags: rest, curl, postman, forgerock

I am trying to test rest api as mentioned [here](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openidm/4.5/integrators-guide/#granting-roles-manually) from Postman. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman) thread here and tried importing the curl request in Postman but it's failing with the following error:

[image]

Here is the complete curl command:

```
curl \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Username: openidm-admin" \
 --header "X-OpenIDM-Password: openidm-admin" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --request PATCH \
 --data '[
    {
       "operation": "add",
       "field": "/members/-",
       "value": {"_ref" : "managed/user/scarter"}
    }
 ]' \
 "http://localhost:8080/openidm/managed/role/cedadaed-5774-4d65-b4a2-41d455ed524a"
{
  "_id": "cedadaed-5774-4d65-b4a2-41d455ed524a",
  "_rev": "2",
  "name": "employee",
  "description": "Role granted to workers on the company payroll"
}
```

Comment: curl request is not valid.. valid till `"http://localhost:8080/openidm/managed/role/cedadaed-5774-4d65-b4a2-41d455ed524a"` not sure what you;re trying then!

Comment: You better create it manually adding head header and parameters