# how to hit curl -k command using postman

Tags: curl, postman

I want to hit below curl command using postman

`curl -k  https://anthos.nalphatech.co.in/ping -v --resolve anthos.nalphatech.co.in:443:10.200.0.12`
but when I import this it is not responding and give a message `Could not send request`
but in Linux machine it is working as expected

Comment: Postman can't handle the `--resolve` part. Thus it's trying to resolve `anthos.nalphatech.co.in` but cannot find a valid ip, thus cannot send the request. You can either use the correct ip in the request or update your /etc/hosts file

Comment: @DivyangDesai Did you try executing the request? The problem is the `--resolve` part which tells curl what IP to use for that host. This isn't (yet?) supported in postman, thus postman won't be able to resolve this address ...

Comment: @derpirscher is there any other way so i can test my api response

Comment: Like said above: Postman needs to determine the IP address it should connect to. There are only 2 ways: 1) you use the  IP instead of the hostname in the request, 2) you make that hostname resolve to the correct IP at least on your system (via `/etc/hosts`)

Comment: This would help in answering your question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68881736/20416874