# Flutter how to pass form data to api

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

I Have a form to get data from the user. The objective is to pass the form data as an object to the Api. The Form is as follows.

```
    Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
     Seperator(),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add a title',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Seperator(),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add a description',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Seperator(),
    TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add a Price',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Seperator(),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Select Unit',
                        ),
                      ),
Button(
                    isProcessing: isProcessing,
                    name: 'Create Post',
                    onPressed: () {
                      final formdata = _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      createpost(formdata); // Api Function
                    },
]

// Api Function
    createpost(AddPost formdata) async {
        try {
          final service = PostService();
          final response =
              await service.createpost(formdata);
        } catch (error) {
          setErrorMessage(error.toString());
        }
```

How can I pass the Form data as an object to the Api Function?

Comment: can you share which client you are using for the api's?

Comment: and also add the code for it

Comment: And add where you are passing the headers to your post request. That will solve your issue, if you jsonDecode it and specify the type of header as form encoded.

Comment: @AsimJawad im using dio for api call

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its help to you in this answer I have send data to API

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can run the API in Postman and use autogenerated code in your flutter app. You can also convert your curl request into postman request using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman) and then use auto generated code

You can also use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to pass form data. here is an example

```
var dio = Dio();
 var formData = FormData.fromMap({
 'name': 'wendux',
  'age': 25,
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt',filename: 
 'upload.txt')
 });
  var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```