# How to post JSON String NOT Object in request body?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The body is String similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHf6c.png). I tried many different ways as below, but none worked.

```
await http.post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: "3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8",      // "'a' is invalid within a number, immediately after a sign character
  // body: "\"3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8\"",  // The JSON value could not be converted to
  // body: jsonEncode("3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8"), // The JSON value could not be converted to
  // body: jsonEncode("\"3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8\""), // The JSON value could not be converted to
  // body: jsonEncode(jsonDecode('3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8')),  // FormatException: Missing expected digit (at character 3)
  // body: jsonEncode(jsonDecode("\"3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8\"")),  // The JSON value could not be converted to
);
```

Comment: are you able to run the api in postman ?

Comment: Yes, I run the api in postman and it works without any problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274083/flutter-how-to-pass-form-data-to-api/69274760#69274760 checkout this

Comment: @WaliKhan Thank you so much. Please, post your answer so that I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: did it please check

Comment: Thanks @WaliKhan I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use postman to autogenerate code like this [image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242338/9863904) given by Wali Khan. The solution is

```
final request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.addAll({
  "content-type": "application/json",
});
request.body = json.encode("3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8");
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the `content-type` to `application/json`, you can't pass a string, only an object, like:

```
body: jsonEncode({"value": "3ea9554d-7a1f-4f20-f6f5-08da74d069a8"})
```

To pass your string as you'd like, set the content type like this:

```
"content-type": "text/plain"
```

But according to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) you can try to remove the `headers` part completely, since it seems that it will be `text/plain` automatically if you pass a string as body.

Comment: Using text/plain returns 415 Unsupported Media Type which is also the same result I get on Postman when using text/plain instead of application/json.

Comment: Maybe the endpoint does not allow plain text body then.